# Trying to deploy to heroku but keep getting rejected

Tags: python, git, heroku

[image]I'm trying to deploy on heroku, which is seeming to be the most complicated I've dealt with since programming. I'm getting an error that I don't have a Procfile and I do. It's only named Procfile. Not ProcFile or Procfile.txt. After I run

```
 git push heroku master
```

I get the following error

```
 Counting objects: 8524, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (7522/7522), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (8524/8524), 14.00 MiB | 2.67 MiB/s, done.
    Total 8524 (delta 2214), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Python app detected
    remote:  !     Warning: Your application is missing a Procfile. This file tells Heroku how to run your application.
    remote:  !     Learn more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
    remote: -----> Installing python-2.7.11
    remote:      $ pip install -r requirements.txt
    remote:        Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
    remote:          Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py2-none-any.whl (81kB)
    remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==0.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
    remote:          Downloading dj-database-url-0.4.0.tar.gz
    remote:        Collecting dj-static==0.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
    remote:          Downloading dj-static-0.0.6.tar.gz
    remote:        Collecting Django==1.9.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
    remote:          Downloading Django-1.9.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6MB)
    remote:        Collecting django-crispy-forms==1.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
    remote:          Downloading django_crispy_forms-1.6.0-py2-none-any.whl (178kB)
    remote:        Collecting django-haystack==2.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
    remote:          Downloading django_haystack-2.4.1-py2-none-any.whl (95kB)
    remote:        Collecting django-taggit==0.18.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
    remote:          Downloading django_taggit-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    remote:        Collecting django-toolbelt==0.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
    remote:          Downloading django-toolbelt-0.0.1.tar.gz
    remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.4.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
    remote:          Downloading gunicorn-19.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112kB)
    remote:        Collecting Pillow==3.1.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
    remote:          Downloading Pillow-3.1.1.tar.gz (10.1MB)
    remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
    remote:          Downloading psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz (371kB)
    remote:        Collecting pysolr==3.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
    remote:          Downloading pysolr-3.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    remote:        Collecting pytz==2016.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
    remote:          Downloading pytz-2016.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (476kB)
    remote:        Collecting requests==2.9.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
    remote:          Downloading requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (501kB)
    remote:        Collecting static3==0.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
    remote:          Downloading static3-0.6.1.tar.gz
    remote:        Collecting whitenoise==3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
    remote:          Downloading whitenoise-3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    remote:        Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4, dj-database-url, static3, dj-static, Django, django-crispy-forms, django-haystack, django-taggit, psycopg2, gunicorn, django-toolbelt, Pillow, requests, pysolr, pytz, whitenoise
    remote:          Running setup.py install for dj-database-url: started
    remote:            Running setup.py install for dj-database-url: finished with status 'done'
    remote:          Running setup.py install for static3: started
    remote:            Running setup.py install for static3: finished with status 'done'
    remote:          Running setup.py install for dj-static: started
    remote:            Running setup.py install for dj-static: finished with status 'done'
    remote:          Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
    remote:            Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'done'
    remote:          Running setup.py install for django-toolbelt: started
    remote:            Running setup.py install for django-toolbelt: finished with status 'done'
    remote:          Running setup.py install for Pillow: started
    remote:            Running setup.py install for Pillow: finished with status 'done'
    remote:        Successfully installed Django-1.9.4 Pillow-3.1.1 beautifulsoup4-4.4.1 dj-database-url-0.4.0 dj-static-0.0.6 django-crispy-forms-1.6.0 django-haystack-2.4.1 django-taggit-0.18.0 django-toolbelt-0.0.1 gunicorn-19.4.5 psycopg2-2.6.1 pysolr-3.4.0 pytz-2016.1 requests-2.9.1 static3-0.6.1 whitenoise-3.0
    remote: 
    remote:      $ python mysite/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
    remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
    remote:          File "mysite/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    remote:            utility.execute()
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 176, in handle
    remote:            collected = self.collect()
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 98, in collect
    remote:            for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 112, in list
    remote:            for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 28, in get_files
    remote:            directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 299, in listdir
    remote:            for entry in os.listdir(path):
    remote:        OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/mysite/mysite/static'
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Error while running '$ python mysite/manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
    remote:        See traceback above for details.
    remote: 
    remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
    remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
    remote: 
    remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
    remote: 
    remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
    remote: 
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote: 
    remote: !       Push rejected to alt-vera.
```

I don't know what the issue is. I've googled and none of the solutions seem to work. Also, Locally i'm using python 3.5 But In the error message I am seeing

```
 Installing python-2.7.11 Why is that. Could this be part of the error
```

EDIT this is my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi:application --log-file -
```

EDIT: It worked after me doing the same thing over and over

[image]

But now I'm getting a different error message

```
 OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/mysite/mysite/static'
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Error while running '$ python mysite/manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
    remote:        See traceback above for details.
    remote: 
    remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
    remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
    remote: 
    remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
    remote: 
    remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
    remote: 
    remote: Verifying deploy....
    remote: 
    remote: !       Push rejected to alt-vera.
    remote: 
    To https://git.heroku.com/alt-vera.git
```

Comment: are u trying to collect static assets ?

Comment: thanks for responding. I'm just trying to deploy following the instructions

Comment: You need to create a profile (call it `Profile`) and then **add it to your repository** with `git add Procfile`, then **commit your changes** with `git commit -m "adding procfile"` then finally, `git push heroku master`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your application is missing the **procfile** add it and then try.
for help https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile 
example for Procfile

```
web:python manage.py runserver
web: gunicorn your-app-name.wsgi --log-file -
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Comment: thanks for the response. My Procfile is in the same directory as my requirements.txt. That's my issue

Comment: @losee  that's not a problem.  I added example for procfile have a look.

Comment: this is still not working. Am I supposed to have Procfile with a period on the end? Like This Procfile. I don't get why it's not reading my procfile

Comment: @losee how you are deploying it through command line or through website ?

Comment: Through command line. I'm literally at my wits end. Ive deleted the file created it using touch and echo based on other posts concerning this topic and nothing. Is there anything ou there besides heroku thats easier or is it all like this as far as deployment is concerned? This is crazy

Answer (score 1):

Coming to this rather late, so not sure if this will be helpful. I found your question because I was having the same problem: I used the Heroku-supplied Django template and definitely had a Procfile in the root of the project.

Which folder did you do `$ git init` in?

My mistake was that I had created a folder ('WEB_CODE') on my desktop to hold this project and initialized THIS folder as a git repo. This meant that the Django app was being installed in a sub-folder at WEB_CODE/myapp, so the Procfile was at the root of myapp, which was not the head of the git repo.

I scrapped this and started over. I now have a new folder to hold everything (suppose it's called 'APP_CODE'), and once I installed the Heroku-supplied Django app, I made the subdirectory which was created from this installation the head of the git repo (eg: APP_CODE/myapp is the repo, not APP_CODE). Consequently, the Procfile was then in the root of the project.

I committed the changes, pushed to my personal github, and then I re-tried the `$heroku create` and `$ git push heroku master` commands and they worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if Late but i discovered it lately after 2 hours googling to find an answer 
The PROBLEM was that i renamed the file "procfile" with lowercase p. So I renamed it to "Procfile" with Uppercase P. then i recreated the git repo then added them to stage then committed them. after that i pushed my branch in my case "master" to heroku and it worked fine for me.

I'm just saying it in case any one got stucked in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this frustrating problem, but I finally got my procfile to work. 1st make sure that you name it "Procfile" without a ".exe" or ".txt" or ".bat". Just "Procfile". For Django I included the following each in it's own line inside the Procfile:

```
web:python manage.py runserver 
web: gunicorn app-name.wsgi  
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Then even if you have done this before, you need to use cmd to cd into the file where your project is and enter the following commands and hit  after each command:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
git init
git add .
git status
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this problem, create the Procfile with the command, not by renaming a created-file:

```
echo web:..etc>Procfile       (without spaces)
```